# Одновременный перебор нескольких значений

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    string t1 = "L", t2 = "u", t3 = "k", t4 = "c", t5 = "y";
    string temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5;
    temp1 = '0', temp2 = '0', temp3 = '0', temp4 = '0', temp5 = '0';
    while ((t1 != temp1) && (t2 != temp2) &&
           (t3 != temp3) && (t4 != temp4) && (t5 != temp5))
    {
        temp1 = rand() % 'a' + 32;
        temp2 = rand() % 'a' + 32;
        temp3 = rand() % 'a' + 32;
        temp4 = rand() % 'a' + 32;
        temp5 = rand() % 'a' + 32;
        cout << temp1 << temp2 << temp3 << temp4 << temp5; system("cls");
    }

    cout << temp1 << temp2 << temp3 << temp4 << temp5;

    return 0;
}
```

Эта код должен "искать" каждый символ, пока не найдет нужный. Но как бы это всё в унисон организовать... Можно напичкать циклами, каждый из которых ищет свой символ по очереди, но это долго, потому что оригинальное слово другое и большое.  Сейчас даже не представляю, как заставить перебирать все символы подряд, а так же, останавливая перебор символа, когда он найден, продолжая искать другие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так вам надо зрелищ или подбор? Подбор - все символы начинаются с a и идут, меняясь одновременно, пока не будет получен нужный...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string res = "Qwertyui";
    string att = "AAAAAAAA";
    for(;res != att;)
    {
        cout << att << '\r';
        for(int i = 0; i < att.length(); ++i)
            if (att[i] != res[i]) att[i]++;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms); // задержка для зрелищности :)
    }
    cout << att << endl;
}
```